# modify kernel parameters in linux without using sysctl

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, proc, sysctl

I have an embedded system. An old linux OS runs on it. When i enter "uname -r" command i get the version information as "3.3.8-3.4".

I want to modify some of network kernel parameters (increase tcp receive buffer size etc.) in /proc/sys. But sysctl command does not exist in this old linux kernel version. Also sysctl.conf does not exist under /etc directory

I tried changing kernel parameter files manually but system does not allow this operation even for super user.

How can i modify kernel parameters in this linux version?

Comment: Might be, that this is no SO-question. Try super user or unix/linux.

Comment: unfortunately sudo command is not exist in my simplified embedded linux os

Answer (score 2):

You can use `/proc/sys`. For example the following command:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

... is basically the same as

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

---

However, you'll need to make sure on your own that parameters will be set on boot.

Comment: i tried it and it works, thank you. but there is something i don't understand. what is the meaning of the echo here? i can't modify any of files under /proc/sys with vi, cat or any other program but echo modifies them. is it a feature of echo or something else?

Comment: It was a typo. It should be ip_forward, not ip_forwarding. Corrected that